# Property or method "cancella" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this problem. After doing my "delete" function on a script, I can't use it. The name of the title is the phrase that appears on the terminal. Does anyone know where the error could be?

This is my template

```
template: '<li> <div> <img width="15" height="15" src="img/trash.png" alt="icon_trash" @click="cancella()">{{todo.name }} </div> </li>'
})
```

With this template, I have a list with an image next to it. when you click on the image, it will remove my todo.name

This is for template

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    props: ['todo'],
    template: '<li> <div> <img width="15" height="15" src="img/trash.png" alt="icon_trash" @click="cancella()">{{todo.name }} </div> </li>'
})
```

This is the function for Fetch

```
@PostMapping("rimuovi")
   public void rimuovi(@RequestBody EntryList item) {
      al.remove(item.getId());
   }
```

This is my function cancella

```
cancella: function()
            {            
                  var rimozione=
                  {
                     id: 0,
                     name: this.product,
                  }

                  console.log(JSON.stringify(rimozione));

                  fetch('rimuovi', 
                  {
                     method: 'post',
                     headers: 
                     {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                     },
                     body: JSON.stringify(rimozione),  
                  })
             }
```

Comment: The function is probably declared where it shouldn't be declared. I've never used Vue.js, but from these docs I can understand that **methods** should be declared in the `methods` component property: https://flaviocopes.com/vue-methods/ . So you should move `cancella` slightly before `template` and wrap it inside `methods`

Comment: the delete function is declared in the `methods` component property. If I move `template` under the `methods` I also have the problem

Comment: are you **100%** sure that it's exactly as expected? please take this example to reproduce your issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwjYep?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks a lot, i resolved my problem.